# Live preview is not available

Tags: bug, status-norepro, asking-questions, markdown-preview, editor

A few minutes ago, I posted a question on MSE and noticed that live preview is not available when writing a question.

I would like to ask if other users have encountered this problem too.

Thanks!

Comment: It is available to me as I write this. Is it still not available for you?  If so you might want to include some details on your set-up in particular the browser you use.

Comment: I just checked now to see it's also working properly for me, although somewhat slowly, on my Windows $7$ machine using Firefox.

Comment: Maybe a screenshot?

Comment: It is available by now ;)

Comment: In the future, when reporting a bug include your browser (with version) and operating system (with version), and any other technical details. Also, as a general tip, try to use a different computer if possible, and a different browser or private/incognito mode as well, just to make sure that this is not some local issue with your computer or browser.

Comment: I got it @AsafKaragila. I am still surprised that I forgot to include a screenshot.